# Method PlayAtTime AVAudioPlayerNode IOS Xamarin doesn't work

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, avaudioengine, avaudioplayernode

I want to play sound at specific time,
I used Method `PlayAtTime` on `AVAudioPlayerNode`
this is my code:

```
 private AVAudioUnitReverb reverb;
 private AVAudioEngine engine;
 private AVAudioFile file;
 private AVAudioPlayerNode audioPlayerNode;

 public void PlayBackgroundMusic(byte[] data, string extention, string filename, double playingAt)
    {
        try
        {
            NSError err;
            engine = new AVAudioEngine();
            audioPlayerNode = new AVAudioPlayerNode();
            engine.AttachNode(audioPlayerNode);

            filename = filename.Replace(@"/", @"%2F").Replace(" ", @"%20");
            NSUrl url = new NSUrl(filename);
            file = new AVAudioFile(url, out err);

            reverb = new AVAudioUnitReverb();
            reverb.LoadFactoryPreset(AVAudioUnitReverbPreset.SmallRoom);

            engine.AttachNode(reverb);

            ConnectAudioNodes(audioPlayerNode, /*timePitch,*/ reverb, engine.OutputNode);

            audioPlayerNode.Stop();                

            engine.StartAndReturnError(out err);
            var hostTime = AVAudioTime.HostTimeForSeconds(playingAt);
            audioPlayerNode.ScheduleFile(file, new AVAudioTime(hostTime), null);
            audioPlayerNode.PlayAtTime(new AVAudioTime(hostTime));                   

            backgroundSong = filename;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MetricsManager.TrackEvent($"AudioService.PlayBackgroundMusic error {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
```

but the code does not working.
The audio is always start from beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Your `PlayAtTime` needs to be based upon the audio player instance(s) that you are delaying and/or sync'ing together.

Obtain the *current time* from `AVAudioPlayer.DeviceCurrentTime` and add the number of seconds (double based) in the future that you wish to start the player:

#### Example:

```
var player1 = AVAudioPlayer.FromUrl(new NSUrl("FireplaceWoodCrackle.mp3", ""), out NSError nsError);
Debug.WriteLine(nsError?.Description);
if (nsError == null)
    player1.PlayAtTime(player1.DeviceCurrentTime + 10); // play at 10 seconds in the future
```

Comment: thanks for answer my question, 

i already try like that, but the audio is not playing, i can't hear the audio

Comment: @HarizalHilmi If you just call the `Play()` method instead of `PlayAtTime()`, does that work?

Comment: yes,
and if i use my code above, the audio is playing but, always start at begining,,

Comment: @HarizalHilmi `always start at beginning` ? `PlayAtTime` is a delay to start playing the audio at a future time, it is not a time within the audio timeline. `AVAudioPlayer` has a `CurrentTime` Property that you can set if you are looking to seek to a different time within the audio